# Kite- Python installation

Tags: python, kite

I was trying to install kite for python development

I have installed the software but it does not open. I see the following error

> kite was unable to listen on port 46624. this usually means another
>   instance of kites is already running kite will now exit

Comment: Can you check if you have another instance of kite already running?

Comment: i was just installed and this problem was occurring from the beginning ,

Comment: Can you check via ps that there actually is nothing else running and connected to port 46624?

Comment: okey, i am checking this and thanks for your help